# JSON encode Go struct with a proto child

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a Go struct that has a proto child like this

```
type Animal struct {
    name string
    attributes *apb.Attributes
}
```

where apb.Attributes is a protobuf message.

using json.Marshal() and passing the struct doesn't seem to work, do I need to create the attributes child as a Go struct instead of adding the proto directly?

Comment: It doesn't work because both fields are unexported. As the `Marshal` documentation states, it can only marshal exported fields.

Comment: @adrian please copy your comment to the answer